# Clearing Cell Values Within HTML

Tags: jquery, html, replace, cell

In my HTML code, I've got a certain cell whose value should be cleared if a link button is pressed. I'd like to achieve this using jQuery and here's how I tried to do it but with no results:

```
var $delActionDate = $('#delete_Event');

        $delActionDate.live('click', function() {

            var myRow = $delActionDate.parent().parent();
            myRow.find('#dateCell').html() = "";
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luca said, to update the html content you use `html("")` rather than `html()=""`.

In additions, assuming your parent() stuff is correct based on your HTML, the change you need to make so that the selected row is based on which button is pressed should be: change

```
var myRow = $delActionDate.parent().parent();
```

to

```
var myRow = $(this).parent().parent();
```

Comment: Remember to create a jquery object from this if you want to call the .parent() method.
var myRow = $(this).parent().parent();

Comment: Your solution worked very well, thanks JacobM. Except that you should change this to $(this) otherwise you cannot call .parent()
I'm thankful to everyone for the tips!

Answer (score 2):

You want, `myRow.find('#dateCell').html("");`

Comment: That's exactly what I want. The only problem here is, I've got multiple rows, no matter what button I click it's always the first row's cell value being emptied. How can I point it to the cell value of the button being pressed?

Comment: @Hallaghan - Are you using an ID multiple times? That's invalid HTML that will give all sorts of issues :)

Comment: Indeed, I'm doing it the wrong way. But I think your approach already cleared my mind in some aspects. I'm going to give it a try and change my code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use classes instead of IDs since there are multiple elements, then use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get where you want, like this:

```
$('.delete_Event').live('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.dateCell').empty();
});
```

This means changing your elements to `class="delete_Eevent"` and `class="dateCell"` instead of `id="delete_Event"` and `id="dateCell"`.  [`.closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to climb up to the `<tr>`, not matter how deep, then does a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to go down to the date cell.  Then we're using [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to clear the elements.

If you have any data or event handlers this is a better approach than [`.html("")`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), because it won't leak the memory stored in [`$.cache`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L4), which [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) cleans up.